В каждом проекте IDE сообщение Kotlin not configured
В каждом, даже новом проекте IDE начало появляться сообщение Kotlin not configured. Пробовала перезапускать, переписать код в новом, только что созданном проекте, выбрать версию компиллера выше, ничего не помогает. Как можно исправить проблему, подскажите пожалуйста.

¿Может стоит нажать кнупку Configure и настроить?

Ну конечно, я пробовала - выбирала при этом актуальную версию компилера. Ничего не меняется. Еще переустановила плагины. Мне тут писали что такая ошибка появляется после обновления но я вроде не обновляла давно... Наверное надо попробовать переустановить саму IDE
